# Toggle selection-change in Vue el-table on button click

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a el-table (Element) in a Vue component with a selection column in it. You can select the checkbox to select multiple items. I need to have the function of selecting the checkbox attached to elements in the table.

```
<el-table
  :data="unit_list"
  @selection-change="handleSelectionChange"
>
  <el-table-column type="selection" />

  <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" >
    <template slot-scope="scope" >
      <span @click="toggleRow(scope.row)" class="click_cell">
       {{ scope.row.name }}
      </span>
    </template>
  </el-table-column>      

  <el-table-column>
    <template slot-scope="scope">
      <div class="no_click_cell">
        You can't click this
      </div>
    </template>
  </el-table-column>

...script

handleSelectionChange(val) {
  this.$emit('selecttionChange', val) // this sends the resulting list to the parent component
}
```

The documentation is not clear as to how you can access the selection change from toggleRow

Comment: how about `@row-click`?

Comment: @Socrates I need to only select certain cells in the row so row-click will not work. But if it was to work, How will I code the function to toggle the selection box?

Answer (score 0):

The method looks like this:

```
//...methods
toggleRow(row){
  this.$refs.unitListTable.toggleRowSelection(row)
}
```

Where unitListTable is your table ref

```
<el-table
  ref="unitListTable"
  :data="checkSearch(unit_list)"
  @selection-change="handleSelectionChange"
>
```